# Use Grails fixture plugin with embedded domains

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, fixtures, grails-domain-class

Given domain classes:

```
class Person {
  String name
  Address address
  static embedded = ['address']
}

class Address {
  String addressLine1
  String addressLine2
  String city
  String state
  String postalCode
  String phone
}
```

Is there a recommended why to create fixtures when using embedded domains?

What I have tried in my fixture file:

```
address1(Address) {
    addressLine1 = '1444 Palm Ave'
    addressLine2 = 'suite 07'
    city = 'Kissiammee'
    state = 'FL'
    postalCode = '34741'
    phone = '615-555-1111'
}

person1(Person) {
    name = 'Fixture Person'
    address = ref('address1')
}
```

In this case person1 gets into the DB with the address1 data embedded in the table as expected, but a row is also added in the address table. When I create a person though the personController in a running application the address row does not get created, and I would like to have my fixtures work similar to that if possible.

This was something I tried on a guess. Didn't work...

```
person2(Person) {
    name = 'Test Person'
    address = [
        addressLine1 : '222 Boone Ave',
        city         : 'Boone',
        state        : 'IA',
        postalCode   : '50210',
        phone        : '515-555-1111',
    ]
}
```

My controller is mostly scaffolded with some small tweaks to handle REST json. If I pass

```
{
  "name":"Rest Fixture person",
  "address":{
    'addressLine1':'333 Boone Ave',
    'city':'Boone',
    ...
  }
}
```

I get the address embedded on the person as expected and no row in the address table as desired. So just wondering if I can pull this same data setup off with the fixture plugin.

Comment: I was apprehending the question incorrectly. Looks like fixture plugin does not take care of `embedded` persistent property. I have a fix for the same in the plugin which I am working on and may submit a pull request eventually.